# Cargar spinner en un layout especifico

Tags: android-studio

Habia conseguido desplegar un spinner en un proyecto pero ahora lo estoy haciendo cargandolo desde diferentes layouts y no consigo que lo muestre, alguna idea de donde meter el codigo que tenia antes en el nuevo proyecto?
[![Esta es la interfaz, los dos botones de arriba estan en un layout, los tres restantes en otro y el espacio en blanco es otro
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnGTT.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnGTT.png)

Este es el codigo del main acticity de primer proyecto donde me funciona.

```
package com.example.instalador.recufinal;

import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String[] caballosLetra;
    private TypedArray caballosFoto;
    private boolean cargar = false;
    private Spinner spinnerDam;
    private ImageView imagenCentral;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        caballosLetra = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.caballoLetra);
        caballosFoto = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.caballoFoto);
        imagenCentral = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagenCentral);
        //Instanciamos el spinner
        spinnerDam = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerDam2);
        spinnerDam.setAdapter(new AdaptadorSpinner(this, R.layout.lineaadapter));
        spinnerDam.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(cargar == false){
                    cargar = true;
                }else {
                    imagenCentral.setImageResource(caballosFoto.getResourceId(position, -1));
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }

    public String[] getCaballosLetra() {
        return caballosLetra;
    }

    public TypedArray getCaballosFoto() {
        return caballosFoto;
    }


}
```

Comment: Desde diferentes layouts, cuales son? Cual es el código que tenias antes?

Comment: el codigo anterior es el que muestro en la pregunta, los layout son 3 en los que tengo en uno dos botones, en otro otros 3 botones y en el ultimo un text view para cambiarlo de color. El formato de la interfaz te lo enseño ahora en una foto

Answer (score 0):

Deberías crear los valores del *Spinner* en el *XML* que se llama **strings.xml** y luego citarlos.

Te dejo la página que explica cómo usarlo.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html